# Javascript Pause

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm using the code below in on of my javascript functions. I want to call this function after 10 seconds. However the function is fired right away!?! Not sure what's going on.

```
<script>
  function testing() {
    //other stuff
    setTimeout(testing2('value'), 10000);
  }
  function testing2(value) {
    //other stuff
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testing2` is called immediately because your wrote it with argument.
`setTimeout` needs a function as first parameter.

And if you write `testing2('value')` javascript of course have to execute your `testing2` at first to get the result and only after that pass the result to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function as an argument, not call the function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // Inside the callback we do what we want.
    testing2('value');
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing the value returned from `testing2('value')` rather than a function into `setTimeout`.

Try this.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    testing2('value');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I wouldn't even mention the other way. "Fixing" something just by wrapping it in quotes to is just too tempting to pass up.